# Does Windows Server 2003 SMTP mail server have a character limit for the subject?

Tags: iis-6, smtp, windows-server-2003

I am using Windows 2003 Server and I'm wondering if the SMTP mail service that is part of IIS (v6.0) has a character limit on the subject line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't; not according to [RFC 2822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt)

It's not SMTP or IIS, but the underlying message that determines the subject.  SMTP is the application layer transport protocol, which abstracts the sending of the e-mail message.  IIS does funky things, but *shouldn't* break standards.

Comment: Correct.  The Subject is buried in the actual message itself and is not a field per se.